# Ember.JS - store a route, then transition to it later

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out a good way to temporarily store a reference to the current route so that I can transition back to it later.

I know that from within a route I can do:

```
r = @get("routeName")
```

and then later:

```
@transitionTo ( r )
```

But that doesn't include dynamic segments. Is there anyway to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
completeRoute = @get("routeName")
args = [completeRoute]
tempRoute = ''
completeRoute.split('.').forEach (route)=>
  tempRoute += route
  args.push(@modelFor(tempRoute)) if @modelFor(tempRoute)
  tempRoute += '.'
```

and then

```
@transitionTo.apply(@, args)
```

I haven't tried this, but I guess something like that might work.

Comment: What if @modelFor returns undefined / the model hasn't yet been created/loaded. My use case for this is I'm transitioning to a login route if the user isn't authenticated. After login, they should be directed back to the route they were on. If a user lands on a route they don't have access to, then the URL will be constructed fully with dynamic elements, but the individual models aren't loaded because the data-store returns 403.

Comment: mmm... yes, that's a hard one. I'll be needing that particular scenario very soon and will work on a solution.  I'll get back to you when I solve it.

Comment: Yeah - in the past I've solved this a different way, but it involved not having a route for the login state and never really transitioning to a login state. But it seems to be ember "wants" routes for every state, so I'm trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One way I solved this in my app was to just use `window.location.pathname` instead of relying on the `routeName` variable. I was serializing to `localStorage`, so it was easier to just store the entire path instead of a bunch of objects.

```
@pathname = window.location.pathname
```

and then, later:

```
@transitionTo(@pathname)
```